# delete table if exists in Microsoft Access

Tags: java, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have one application in which I need to delete table if exit in Microsoft Access Database.
I saw the code [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/java-databases/32033-newbie-question-check-if-table-exists-db.html#post281527). The table name which I want to delete is **data_table** and the access database file name is **local_entry**
so where I need to change the code so it work for my application.

```
public void testDropTable () throws SQLException{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MsAccessDSN");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet checkTable = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "POI", null);
    String tableName = null;
    while (checkTable.next())
    {
        System.out.println("In here");
        tableName = checkTable.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        System.out.println(tableName);
    }
    if (tableName != null){
        try {
            String dropTable = "DROP TABLE ";
            String[] tables = DB_TABLE;
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
                String stringCode = new String();
                stringCode = stringCode + tables[i];
                System.out.println(dropTable + tables[i]);

                // Drop each table in the array.
                int temp = stmt.executeUpdate(dropTable + tables[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in testDropTable (): \n"
                    + "Drop Table testDropTable threw an exception: " +(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    else{
        con.close();
    }
}
```

I think I need to change this two line:

```
String dropTable = "DROP TABLE ";
String[] tables = DB_TABLE;
```

can I change **DROP TABLE** to **data_table** and what about second line. What is this **DB_TABLE**
I change the whole code by this way but till problem is there:

```
public void testDropTable () throws SQLException{
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MsAccessDSN");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet checkTable = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "POI", null);
    String tableName = null;
    while (checkTable.next())
    {
        System.out.println("In here");
        tableName = checkTable.getString("data_table");
        System.out.println(tableName);
    }
    if (tableName != null){
        try {
            String dropTable = "DROP TABLE ";
            String[] tables = {"data_table"};
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
                String stringCode = new String();
                stringCode = stringCode + tables[i];
                System.out.println(dropTable + tables[i]);

                // Drop each table in the array.
                int temp = stmt.executeUpdate(dropTable + tables[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in testDropTable (): \n"
                    + "Drop Table testDropTable threw an exception: " +(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    else{
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MsAccessDSN");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
// Specify the type of object; in this case we want tables
String[] types = {"TABLE"};
ResultSet checkTable = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%", types);
String tableName = null;

while (checkTable.next())
{
    System.out.println("In here");
    tableName = checkTable.getString(3)
    System.out.println(tableName);

    // check if the table 'data_table' exist in your database
    if (tableName.equals("data_table"){    
        try {
            //drop the table if present  
            int temp = stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE " + tableName);
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in testDropTable (): \n"
                + "Drop Table testDropTable threw an exception: " +(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }    
}
con.close;
```

for more information visit here [Metadata](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/DatabaseMetaDatagetTablesStringcatalogStringschemaPatternStringtableNamePatternStringtypes.htm)

Comment: thank bro...
exactly this code work.
And upgrade my question if you like my question.

Comment: @shrish why did you delete that whole block of code from the OPs question? vinitvikash is that code block just unnecessary?

Comment: @gideon its just a line of code that is changed which the OP is asking if its correct.I suppose this question is self sufficient.

Comment: @Shirish11 but you've suggested removing content right from `I think I need...` etc the edit has been rejected already in the queue (not by me)

Comment: @gideon about the edit `I think I need..` in the code the OP is unaware of what the code is actually doing, figuring out some random replacements that will get it working is a wrong notion.And the OP himself suggested for upgrading his question. If he finds he needs to undo the update its up to him

Answer (score 1):

**Drop table table name;** is the command to drop the table in your database.
Try to replace the **DB_TABLE** with **data_table**.

```
String dropTable = "DROP TABLE ";
String[] tables = data_table;
```

---

try this

```
    public void testDropTable () throws SQLException{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MsAccessDSN");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet checkTable = con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "POI", null);
    String tableName = null;
    while (checkTable.next())
    {
        System.out.println("In here");
        tableName = checkTable.getString("data_table");
        System.out.println(tableName);
    }
    if (tableName != null){
        try {
            String dropTable = "DROP TABLE ";
            String[] tables = tableName;
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
                String stringCode = new String();
                stringCode = stringCode + tables[i];
                System.out.println(dropTable + tables[i]);

                // Drop each table in the array.
                int temp = stmt.executeUpdate(dropTable + tables[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in testDropTable (): \n"
                    + "Drop Table testDropTable threw an exception: " +(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    else{
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok chinna ...
actually I made some mistake.
what I need to change in this code:
    tableName = checkTable.getString("TABLE_NAME");
here I need to change TABLE_NAME with data_table ?
and you said that change DB_TABLE with data_table. But tables is collection of string.

Comment: I write the whole code in this way but till it not work in my application:

Comment: hi vinitvikash. you can replace DB_Table with table_name or data_table.  Table_name is actually a string which the value is data_table...

Comment: can you correct the whole code and post it because I also try the above thing but the problem is till there.

Comment: ok..there one error is showing for
String[] tables = tableName;
that is:
Type mismatch: can not convert form String to String[]

Comment: String[] tables = {tableName};

Comment: ya thanx your code work fine.
please up vote if you like my question

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested in this question, i removed the while loop statement in the accepted answer and reduced the code to:

```
public void testDropTable() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MsAccessDSN");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String[] tables = {"data_table"};
        for (String table : tables) {
            try {
                stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE " + table);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Exception in testDropTable (): \n"
                    + "Drop Table testDropTable threw an exception: " +(e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        con.close();
    }
```